# What is the maximum number of characters in TransactionID?

Tags: square, square-connect

Square POS API returns the TransactionID after payment is completed.

What is the maximum number of characters in TransactionID?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure off the top of my head. Can you explain where this will come in handy? Is it for storing in your own database?

Comment: Yes, I want to store it in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum amount of characters for a `transaction_id` is 255.